# Sorting Group on the summation of two values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a field (`PharmacyTotal`) in my report that takes the `SUM` of a field called `Price`:

```
[Sum(Price)]
```

I then have another field(`LabTotal`) that takes the sum of a `LookUpSet` like this:

```
=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Patient_Name.Value, Fields!FULL_NAME.Value, Fields!COST.Value, "DataSet3"))
```

This uses custom code that was sourced [here](http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/).

I'd like to sort my group based off these two values added together. When trying to enter this as as a formular I'd like to sort off of:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox12.Value+ReportItems!Price3.Value
```

I receive the error:

`A sort expression for tablix 'Tablix3' refers to a report item. Report items cannot be used in sort expressions.`

Am I able to sort off of the addition of my two fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort Expression should look like :
=(function which generate Textox12) + (function which is generate Price3)
Also - you can add calculated field in dataset and sort your group by field.